# Java LocalDateTime with offset

Tags: java-8, java-time, timezone-offset

The task is to convert current date time to that format:

```
  2023-06-28T12:00:01.545+0300
```

For this purporse I use the following approach:

```
 String currentDateTime =
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
            .format(LocalDateTime.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

But it returns:

```
 2023-06-28T12:00:01.545
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`, as its name suggests, only produces *local* date times - date times without a zone/offset.

You should use `ISO_DATE_TIME` instead.

Also, getting the current `LocalDateTime` and then adding an offset to it doesn't make much sense to me, not to mention that you are adding an offset of 0 (`UTC`), instead of the +03:00 that you expect in your output.

To get a `OffsetDateTime` at +03:00 that represents the current instant, use the `OffsetDateTime.now` overload that takes a `ZoneId`.

```
String currentDateTime =
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME
                .format(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(3)));
        System.out.println(currentDateTime);
```

Example output:

```
2023-06-28T15:12:05.752631+03:00
```

If you want the offset to be in the format of `+0300` instead, use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, which allows you to specify a custom offset format.

```
String currentDateTime =
        new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                // first append the date time without an offset
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                // then append the offset - here I'm assuming you want "0000" for a 0 offset
                .appendOffset("+HHMM", "0000")
                .toFormatter()
                .format(OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(3)));
        System.out.println(currentDateTime);
```